# Euler-Lagrange equation with extra variable under integral. (Reference request)

Tags: reference-request, calculus-of-variations

Assume that we have a functional to optimize of the form $$\iiint L[x, f_y(y, z), f_z(y,z)]dxdydz.$$
As one may notice, the optimized function $f$ depends only on $y$ and $z$, which means that writing down the Euler-Lagrange will get rid of integral on $y$ and $z$ but the $x$ integration will still be there. So the resulting equation will be rather integro-differential, than usual PDE.

Is there a good reference, which treats the problems like this?

Comment: Set $M(v_y, v_z) := \int L(x,v_y,v_z) \mathrm{d}x$. Then you are just optimizing $\int\int M(f_y, f_z) \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}z$, which is the standard setting for Euler-Lagrange (even with an autonomous Lagrangian). I don't understand the need for another theory here.